# How do I install MultiNEAT using conda?

Tags: python, conda, neat

I'm trying to install MultiNEAT library with the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge multineat
```

The process hangs at "Solving environment" step:

```
conda install -c conda-forge multineat
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: \
```

Is it possible to fix this?

I tried the following commands before installing MultiNEAT again, but it didn't help:

```
conda config --set channel_priority false
```

```
conda update conda
```

```
conda update --all --yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MultiNEAT has not been undergoing active development and so the last build of it on Conda Forge was with Python 3.6. Since this is an EOL version of Python one should not be installing this into an existing environment, but creating a dedicated environment for it. Furthermore, the package metadata provides only lower bounds, which one should expect to be problematic because of API changes. Try something like:

**multineat.yaml**

```yaml
name: multineat
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - multineat
  - boost=1.67
  - matplotlib=2.2
  - numpy=1.11
  - opencv=3.3
```

and create with

```bash
conda env create -n multineat -f multineat.yaml
```